# Javapoet not found in processor

Tags: android, annotations, processor, bintray, javapoet

I created an Android library that uses **JavaPoet** to generate classes. It works well on my local workspace ; even if I include the library module into another project.

Now I'm trying to put my project online through bintray. The project is uploaded correctly, but then when I include it in a new project and build the projet I get this message :

> Error:Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while
>   constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor:
>   Provider me.aflak.filter_processor.FilterProcessor could not be
>   instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/squareup/javapoet/TypeName

I guess it comes from the way I manage the dependencies... Compiletime, Runtime stuff...

This is **processor** build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':filter-annotation')

    api 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc3'
}
```

This is **annotation** buid.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
}
```

This is how I include the library in an empty project :

```
// build.gradle project
repositories {
    maven{
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/omaflak/maven'
    }
}

// build.gradle module
dependencies {
    compile 'me.aflak.libraries:filter-annotation:1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'me.aflak.libraries:filter-processor:1.0'
}
```

Could someone point me out to the right direction ? Thanks !

Comment: Any reason why you use `api` and not `compile` as well?

Comment: I tried both, and both didn't work. But then I looked at Butterknife  processor build.gradle, and `api` was used to include JavaPoet.

Comment: Plus, I think `compile` is deprecated. We should use `implementation` and `api` instead

Comment: In theory it should work with either compile (deprecated) or implementation out of the box, but I don't know why it doesn't for you

Comment: Hmm.. Then maybe it's not the dependency

Comment: You can see the dependencies in the POM for your artifacts. Also you could list the dependencies with Gradle to see if everything is available correctly.

Comment: I did exactly this yesterday, and that's why it's very weird : JavaPoet appears in the POM but it's not being resolved by Gradle...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got the solution (a bit randomly though :p).

I had to add `mavenLocal()` in the library module.

Comment: Could you share the what code you changed because i am facing same problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Nitin Sharma, checkout the gradle files of this project : https://github.com/OmarAflak/Filter-Library?files=1